# How do i put the image behind video by using FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have one video (400x300) and an image (1280x300).
pls show me how can i put this image behind the video like that:
i've try, but not working T-T

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Use the [overlay filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay)

This will overlay the video on top of the image:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.png -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "overlay=(W-w)/2:shortest=1" output.mp4
```

If you need to resize the video then add the [scale filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale):

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.png -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=400:-1[fg];[0:v][fg]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:shortest=1" output.mp4
```

## You can use pad filter instead of an image

If you just want to add black padding you don't need an image and can use the [pad filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad).

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "pad=1280:0:(ow-iw)/2" output.mp4
```

## Using the player to do it instead

You could add the padding upon playback so you don't even need to re-encode:

```
ffplay -vf "pad=1280:0:(ow-iw)/2" input.mp4
```

Comment: thanks you sir! It's work :-bd
by the way, Can u give me another favor !?
If my video isn't 400x300, for example 500x350. and I wanna make it fit to 400x300 then do the action 'v mentioned . 
I always use cmd:"ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -s 400x300 -c:a copy output.mp4"
So how could we convert the video to 400x300 then add image in one command !!
pls help me.  thx so much!!!

Comment: @OYAKHILOMEJOSHUA I added an example using the scale filter. If the answer is good you can accept it by clicking on the green arrow to the left.

Comment: I think you should clarify that your scale will output 400x280 for his hypothetical input of 500x350 instead of 400x300, and thus leave blank space above and below. -1:300 may be a better option, assuming that he doesn't want to distort the image.

Comment: Thanks you so much for supporting me !!!! 
My code skills is too bad T-T
Because i working on asian media business, there are too much suck random resolution (ex: 520x423, 427x340, 608x260, etc) it's make me confused all the time. all i wanna do is :
"with one cmd, we can fit them on constant resolution ex: 600x400, then add the image as we've mentioned"
pls help me @@